# Is there a night light in Raspbian?

Tags: raspbian

I am new to Raspberry Pi and I wanted to know if there is a night light mode in Raspbian (similar to the ones in Ubuntu or MacOs)

Comment: Do you mean "dark mode" where the UI is mostly dark or "night shift" where the blue light is reduced in the late hours?

Comment: Have a look at `apt search redshift`.

Comment: Try posting the question on https://forum.lxde.org as I can't find whether LXDE has a "night shift" mode.